# Separate subdomains on one GitHub page

Tags: github, subdomain, web-hosting, github-pages

I'm looking to host two very different sections of my website in the same GitHub Pages site. For example, say I a section of my website hosts cat videos, and one that hosts dog videos, and both are light enough to fit within the limits of my Pages repo.

What I want is for the link `meow.example.com` to take you to the cat section of the page, and `bark.example.com` to take you to the dog section of the site. This is of course assuming I already own the `example.com` domain on GoDaddy or whatever other domain registrar.

I know for a fact that this can be done (ex: `en.wikipedia.org` vs `es.wikipedia.org`). Is this possible to do with GitHub Pages? If not, what would I be required to do with another hosting service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible to do using GitHub Pages. Custom subdomains are among the types of custom domains supported by GitHub Pages.

For general info, see [About custom domains and GitHub Pages - Using a subdomain for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages#using-a-subdomain-for-your-github-pages-site).

For detailed set-up instructions, see [Managing a custom domain for your GitHub Pages site - Configuring a subdomain](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-a-subdomain)

In essence, the steps to get this set up are:

1. Go to your GitHub repo settings and add your desired subdomain as a "custom domain". This will generate a commit in your GitHub repo that creates a "CNAME" file at the root of your repo, containing your custom subdomain.
2. At your DNS provider (commonly your domain registrar), create a `CNAME` record that points to `[username].github.io`.
3. Wait for the DNS linkage. That's it, you're done.

Comment: So the thing is by using this method, I can have `meow.example.com` OR `bark.example.com`, not both. I need to have `meow.example.com` AND `bark.example.com`, both leading to different sections of the site

Comment: Oh. I may have misread your question. I didn't realize both subdomains need to be managed under a single repo. Subdomains are typically used to separate sites across infrastructure, so it's not very common to have a single repository serve out to multiple subdomains like that. Typically you would use subfolders instead. So as a revised answer, it is impossible to serve multiple subdomains from a single repository using only GitHub Pages. You would need to involve another separate web hosting, CDN or reverse proxying service to get it to work.